# Python: optimal way to create partial data

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, optimization, data-structures

Not sure how to best describe the title for this question.

I would like to be able to store only partial data, based on a user request.  For example, lets say there are a hundred of dictionaries `db1`, `db2`, `db3`, etc.  For simplicity consider:

```
db1 = {'d11': 1,
       'd12': 2}

db2 = {'d21': 3,
       'd22': 4}

db3 = {'d31': 5,
       'd32': 6}
```

Assume these values gets update every second by a different function.

Let's say every minute, I would like to get the state of these information like so.  And for this test lets assume `MINUTES = 10_000_000`:

```
## METHOD 1a
for m in range(MINUTES):
    d = {'d1': db1['d11'],
         'd2': db1['d12'],
         'd3': db2['d21'],
         'd4': db2['d22'],
         'd5': db3['d31'],
         'd6': db3['d32']}
```

Assume I only care about certain keys, depending on the user request.  For simplicity, lets say we only want `d1` and `d4`.  In this scenario, its unnecessary to really store the rest like above.  Technically, I would like something like:

```
## METHOD 2a
for m in range(MINUTES):
    d = {'d1': db1['d11'],
         'd4': db2['d22']}
```

This is my ideal solution, but I dont think I can have this kind of solution.  Because I need to somehow dynamically have this code and the location of which `db` it will extract the data from. The code needs to be somewhere. Is there a way to do it?

I wasnt sure I could do method 2a above (that dynamically update per user request), so I ended up creating a class like so:

```
class GetData():
    def __init__(self, db1, db2, db3, properties):
        self.db1 = db1
        self.db2 = db2
        self.db3 = db3
        self.list_methods = self.update_list_methods(properties)

        for k, v in properties.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

    def update(self, db1, db2, db3):
        self.db1 = db1
        self.db2 = db2
        self.db3 = db3

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

    def update_d1(self):
        self.d1 = self.db1['d11']

    def update_d2(self):
        self.d2 = self.db1['d12']

    def update_d3(self):
        self.d3 = self.db2['d21']

    def update_d4(self):
        self.d4 = self.db2['d22']

    def update_d5(self):
        self.d5 = self.db3['d31']

    def update_d6(self):
        self.d6 = self.db3['d32']

    def update_list_methods(self, properties):
        list_methods = ["update_{}".format(p) for p in properties.keys()]
        return [getattr(self, m) for m in list_methods]

    def update_values(self):
        _ = [m() for m in self.list_methods]
```

It takes in the dbs, plus a dictionary of properties, so that these properties can be initialized.  Only the necessary methods will be saved on the list of methods, so that these can be called every minute.

And the loop will have something like so (for when I want all 6 properties):

```
## METHOD 1b
d = GetData(None, None, None, properties={'d1': None,
                                          'd2': None,
                                          'd3': None,
                                          'd4': None,
                                          'd5': None,
                                          'd6': None})
for m in range(MINUTES):
    d.update(db1, db2, db3)
    d.update_values()
```

I only initialize the object once, then just update its `db`s, then update the values so I can access `d['d1']` or `d['d4']`

And the loop will be something like so (if the user only wants d1 and d4), so its more efficient:

```
## METHOD 2b
d = GetData(None, None, None, properties={'d1': None, 'd4': None})
for m in range(MINUTES):
    d.update(db1, db2, db3)
    d.update_values()
```

The times for each methods are (using pypy3):

```
method 1a: 0.9s
method 1b: 0.7s
method 2a: 2.2s
method 2b: 1.1s
```

Of course the numbers will be better if we are only picking 2 out of 100 or something keys.  My question is, whats the best way to create something that I want here, that's going to be faster than just generating the entire dictionary all the time (with all the keys).  My solution, say method 2b, will be faster than generating the entire dictionary (method 1a) if there are many keys, maybe atleast 12 keys.  Is this the most efficient way to go about this?  Also, with this method, if the user wants all the keys, then method 2a is almost twice as slow as method 1a.  A lot of the overhead seems to be calling each functions for the specific key, where as in the dictionary version, it is just accessing the data with 0(1) time.

Comment: One thing confusing me about the `for m in …` you present is `m` not getting used. Have a look at [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: (If this was Code Review@SE, I'd vote to close for lack of review context.)

Comment: I have trouble understanding your problem. I am lost at "This is my ideal solution..." and can't go further. What does it mean " The code needs to be somewhere."

Comment: What I mean is that you cannot hard code method2a.  Since the keys are based on user request, on run time.  The value of the dictionary has to call a function to get the value, and wont be the same performance that just accessing the data.  Which is basically same as how method1b and method2b works.  Using the descriptors is a big help though

Comment: Though I guess I could also do exec(), and have the string be based on the user request, but seems exec is frowned upon